# Where to put implementation templates realized by C macros?

Tags: c, templates, design-patterns, libraries, c99

I want a write a C library with macro-templates depending on a type.

A very simplified example for the header file:

```
#define PAIR_TEMPLATE(Type) \
typedef struct { Type a[2]; } PAIR_ ## Type; \
Type Pair_ ## Type ## _Sum (PAIR_ ## Type *pPair);

PAIR_TEMPLATE (char)

PAIR_TEMPLATE (int)
```

This should expand to

```
typedef struct { char a[2]; } PAIR_char;
char Pair_char_Sum (PAIR_char *pPair);

typedef struct { int a[2]; } PAIR_int;
int Pair_int_Sum (PAIR_int *pPair);
```

The implementation for `Sum` can also be templated:

```
#define PAIR_Sum_TEMPLATE(Type) \
Type Pair_ ## Type ## _Sum (PAIR_ ## Type *pPair) { \
  return (Type) (pPair->a [0] + pPair->a [1]); \
}
```

Please note that this is only a very simplified example. My real template will have multiple other functions and will be also applicable for almost any `struct` type. Think of it as of a template for a dynamic array.

My library itself will use this template for some data types. On the other hand, the user of the library should also be able to use this template for other types.

Now I am facing a design problem: How to ensure that there will not be multiple expansions of the `typedef`-template with the same name in the same translation unit (because this is not allowed by the compiler)? Maybe the user of the library will expand the `typedef`-template for some types himself, but he does not see for which types this is already done in the library headers. Moreover, the library could be updated one day and add more types internally such that new conflicts might be added to the user's code after an update. Should the library manual require to define a macro with a certain name like `#define PAIR_TEMPLATE_DEFINED_[Type]` after each expansion and require to put every expansion into `#ifndef ... #endif`? Or is there a better solution?

Another problem follows:

If I put the implementation template (not the header template!) into a separate code file which is supposed to be compiled in a translation unit different from the user's code, it will be difficult for the user to expand the implementation template for his own types.

On the other hand, if I put the implementation template into the library header file such that the user of my library will expand the implementation in the same translation unit, then he will have difficulties ensuring that, for every type, there is at most one implementation expanded.

Is there a good design solution for this conflict? Thank you.

Comment: You need to separate the template instantiations from the template declarations.  The declarations allow the types to be used in multiple files.  The definitions should be instantiated separately, compiled separately, etc.  If the instantiations are in a library, then there won't be repeats (at least, it won't matter if there are repeats; only one will be linked).

Comment: So I should have one file `mylib/include/pair-declaration-template.h` and `mylib/src/pair-implementation-template.h` with only the macros? If the library needs the `int` type, then it should also have `mylib/include/pair-int-decl.h`, `mylib/src/pair-int-impl.c`? But if the user also needs the `int` type, he will also expand the template and then there will be two `typedef`s with the same name in the same translation unit because he also includes the library headers in his main translation unit. Or is there no other way than listing the types which are already expanded in the lib?

Comment: More or less.  You should be able to share the declarations — what must be controlled is the implementations.  That is, the declaration of 'pair `int`' can be shared, but there must be only one definition.

Comment: Nitpick: you have a semicolon-space-backslash-newline combo at the end of the `PAIR_TEMPLATE` macro definition.  I think it would look better if you omitted the backslash (which makes the blank line after the macro into a part of the macro) and the semicolon, so that the invoker should write `PAIR_TEMPLATE(int);` with the semicolon.  It is rarely a good idea to end a macro definition with a semicolon.

Comment: I removed the backslash. That was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: You said that declarations can be shared. But I get a compile error upon multiple equivalent `typedef`s. I added a new paragraph into the question where I also ask about this.

Comment: Use a header guard in any case.

Comment: @thebusybee, I can guard headers, but how can I guard function-like macros such they cannot be expanded with the same argument multiple times?

Comment: You cannot do this, as you cannot guard non-macro function definitions against multiple occurences in the same translations unit. Using C requires some discipline in programming, perhaps a bit more than in other languages. That's why we get compiler diagnostics. As a programmer, I prefer being notified if my code is wrong or weird, instead of being pampered. The automation would hide potential logical errors in my implementation. -- However, what you are trying here seems to be a feature of OOP. Why don't you use a OOP language?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My language should be widely used, capable of doing low-level stuff and not need an interpreter. C++ might also be possible, but as a programmer, I would rather have a little bit more work to do than use something which I do not fully understand. Even compiler vendors usually have issues with supporting a full C++ standard.

Comment: Which way is better to make the `typedef` declaration of a specific type `PAIR_int` visible for its implementation? A. In the source file `src/pair-int-impl.c` where the implementation macro for `PAIR_int` will be expanded, include the file `src/pair-int-decl.h` where the declaration macro is expanded? B. Make the declaration macro be part of the implementation macro? Is A. or B. better?